# How to add custom xib for iPad

Tags: objective-c

I have created my app for iPad using storyboard.

I want to add one more xib for iPad. so for that I am using empty xib.

But there is no option to choose either iPhone or iPad xib.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of your xib down as you see in the photo, the important thing is to leave unchanged the option inferred.
Otherwise  you can change it to your custom size.

I hope I have helped you!

Bye[image]